# Java jTable column listener

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `jtable` (Gui layout manager) with `boolean` value in one column.
You will see that there will be a checkbox appearing in this column. 
That's all fine with me but now I would like to have a column cell event listener so I get output of the entire row data when I press this checkbox.

Now I have some success with the `jtable.getModel().addTableModelListener` , but this has impact on the whole table.

```
jTabelRooster.getModel().addTableModelListener(
new TableModelListener() {
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent evt) {

        String lidnummer = jTabelRooster.getValueAt(evt.getLastRow(), 0).toString();
        int parseLidnummer = Integer.parseInt(lidnummer);
        String lidVoornaam = jTabelRooster.getValueAt(evt.getLastRow(), 1).toString();
        String lidAchternaam = jTabelRooster.getValueAt(evt.getLastRow(), 3).toString();
        Boolean aanwezig = Boolean.parseBoolean(jTabelRooster.getValueAt(evt.getLastRow(), 4).toString());

    }
});
```

can somebody hell me in this matter?

Comment: Please reply to the answers to this question. It's the least you could do for them: to acknowledge their efforts given gratis for your benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just override the [`setValueAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) function of your tablemodel? It gets the two coordinates in the tablemodel, and the value the user entered

```
class YourTableModel extends YourBaseTableModel
{
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        //To keep the default behavior, if you didn't write this method yourself
        super.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex);
        if(columnIndex == theBooleanColumnIndex)
        {
            //now with rowIndex you can access the underlaying row
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now I have some success with the jtable.getModel().addTableModelListener , but this has impact on the whole table.

Listen for events generated by a change in the column containing the Boolean:

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
{
    if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE)
    {
        int column = e.getColumn();

        if (column == ???)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```